# beautifulsoup get text by spaces between span tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
rr = []

bs_add = result.find('span', {'class': 'address'})#.text#.replace('\n', ' ')

print(bs_add)
print(bs_add.attrs)
print(bs_add.get_text())
```

and this code gives me result like that:

```
<span class="address"><span>595 Buckingham Way Ste 331</span>San Francisco, CA 94132</span>
{'class': ['address']}
595 Buckingham Way Ste 331San Francisco, CA 94132
```

the problem in this section: gives me the result: `595 Buckingham Way Ste 331San Francisco, CA 94132`

but I need a result like that: `595 Buckingham Way Ste 331 San Francisco, CA 94132`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to achieve?

You are close to your goal, just specify a character or string for your `.get_text()` method to join the bits of extracted text together - In this case a whitespace:

```
bs_add.get_text(' ', strip=True)
```

or use `stripped_strings` for same result:

```
' '.join(bs_add.stripped_strings)
```

#### Output

```
595 Buckingham Way Ste 331 San Francisco, CA 94132
```

Comment: another code like above a do `bs_add.get_text(' ', strip=True)` and give me result `Showing 1-30 of 2143 1 2 3 4 5 Next` I want to get just number `2143`. can you check it pleas

Comment: This would be predestined to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), as presumably the condition as well as the tag to be selected looks different. You should include these details in your new well asked question, would be great - we will see it and help you further. Would assume you have to select the tag more specific.

Comment: you can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70807202/beautifulsoup-get-text-by-exclude-some-tag-or-remove-some-text