# How to extract number of max results from pagination with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to select the pagination section and like to extract the number of max results `2143`:

```
numbers = contents.find(name="div", attrs={"class": "pagination"})
print(numbers .attrs)
print(numbers )
print(numbers .get_text(' ', strip=True))
```

and this code gives me result like that:

```
    {'class': ['pagination']}
    <div class="pagination"><span>Showing 1-30 of 2143</span><ul><li><div class="prev"></div></li><li><span class="disabled">1</span></li><li><a data-analytics='{"click_id":132,"module":1,"listing_page":2}' data-page="2" data-remote="true" href="/san-francisco-ca/dentists?page=2">2</a></li><li><a data-analytics='{"click_id":132,"module":1,"listing_page":3}' data-page="3" data-remote="true" href="/san-francisco-ca/dentists?page=3">3</a></li><li><a data-analytics='{"click_id":132,"module":1,"listing_page":4}' data-page="4" data-remote="true" href="/san-francisco-ca/dentists?page=4">4</a></li><li><a data-analytics='{"click_id":132,"module":1,"listing_page":5}' data-page="5" data-remote="true" href="/san-francisco-ca/dentists?page=5">5</a></li><li><a class="next ajax-page" data-analytics='{"click_id":132}' data-page="2" data-remote="true" href="/san-francisco-ca/dentists?page=2">Next</a></li></ul></div>
    Showing 1-30 of 2143 1 2 3 4 5 Next
```

How to extract the `2143` only:

`Showing 1-30 of 2143 1 2 3 4 5 Next`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your tag more specific, one option ist to use `css selectors` to chain conditions - Select first direct `<span>` of `<div>` with class `pagination`, split the text by whitespace and grab the last element of the list:

```
soup.select_one('div.pagination > span').text.split(' ')[-1]
```

#### Example

```
html = '''<div class="pagination"><span>Showing 1-30 of 2143</span><ul><li><div class="prev"></div></li><li><span class="disabled">1</span></li><li><a data-analytics='{"click_id":132,"module":1,"listing_page":2}' data-page="2" data-remote="true" href="/san-francisco-ca/dentists?page=2">2</a></li><li><a data-analytics='{"click_id":132,"module":1,"listing_page":3}' data-page="3" data-remote="true" href="/san-francisco-ca/dentists?page=3">3</a></li><li><a data-analytics='{"click_id":132,"module":1,"listing_page":4}' data-page="4" data-remote="true" href="/san-francisco-ca/dentists?page=4">4</a></li><li><a data-analytics='{"click_id":132,"module":1,"listing_page":5}' data-page="5" data-remote="true" href="/san-francisco-ca/dentists?page=5">5</a></li><li><a class="next ajax-page" data-analytics='{"click_id":132}' data-page="2" data-remote="true" href="/san-francisco-ca/dentists?page=2">Next</a></li></ul></div>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

soup.select_one('div.pagination > span').text.split(' ')[-1]
```

#### Output

```
2143
```

Comment: this code: `soup.select_one('div.pagination > span').text.split(' ')[3]` work like code above

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `numbers.get_text`, `find` "span", get text and `rsplit` by 1 and take the second element:

```
out = numbers.find('span').text.rsplit(' ', 1)[1]
```

Output:

```
'2143'
```